# Output of for loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am running a for loop inside a while loop.

File passed as parameter has the contents:

```
peter
roger
casie
```

I am trying to create a path to test existence of files a,b,c,d,e

I am expecting the output to be

```
/peter/a
/peter/b
```

and so on.

Instead I am getting

```
/aeter
/beter
```

etc.

What do I need to understand here? Please find the code below -

CODE:

```
while read fileLine; do
  x=$fileLine
  for i in a b c d e
  do
    echo /$x/$i
  done
done < $1
```

Comment: Works fine with bash 4.2.8 and Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your input file uses the windows end-of-line format of `\r\n`. The `read` removes the `\n` but leaves the `\r`. When the string `/$x/$i` is printed, the "carriage" is returned to the beginning of the line at the end of the `x` string, printing the slash over top of the slash from `x` and printing the letter from `i` over the first letter of `x`.

You may be able to fix it by replacing your `x=$fileLine` line with

```
x=${fileLine%?}
```

which should remove the last character.